# mod_security default_SESSION.pag file huge size

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

default_SESSION.pag file showing 575G though df -h showing less.

> /dev/xvda1       40G   19G   19G  51% /

What for this default_SESSION.pag file actually used? It is updated when there is entries coming in error log.

```
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: MODSEC_2.5
Define: MODSEC_2.9
User: name="daemon" id=2
Group: name="daemon" id=2

SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecRequestBodyLimit 1048576000
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 10485760
SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 10485760
SecRequestBodyLimitAction Reject

SecResponseBodyAccess Off
SecResponseBodyLimit          10000000

SecPcreMatchLimit 1500000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 1500000

SecTmpDir /var/lib/mod_security
SecDataDir /var/lib/mod_security
SecUploadDir /var/lib/mod_security
SecAuditLogStorageDir /var/lib/mod_security
```

Any settings to control the size of this file or purge old entries?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting apache was enough to flush the file clear for me, though I did find some references online to a utiity to clean it, or a modsec setting to empty it. Try restarting?